# How to retrieve values from hashtable after resolving collision using linear probing?

Tags: go, hashtable, hash-collision, linear-probing

I am trying to implement a hash program in go, I did insertion and resolved collisions using linear probing. When I'm trying to retrieve values back, i'm getting different values as I used linear probing to fix collisions.

This is my program : https://play.golang.org/p/7Pmqu6A313

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your solution is that you are using "linear probing" for insert operation, but you are not using the same approach for retrieving it.

First of all - I would change your underlining storage to keep whole struct instead of value:

```
var hasharray [15]Item
```

Second, I would change the retrieve method to check value of the item with calculated hash index, and after that iterate items one by one to find actual item if there was a collision:

```
func retrieve(key string) {
    index := hashmethod(key)
    found := false
    for !found {
        item:= hasharray[index];
        if key == item.key {
         found = true;
         fmt.Println(index, item)
        } else if index != size-1 {
            index++
        } else {
            index = 0
        }
    }   
}
```

See here: https://play.golang.org/p/8JfTpbJcWx